# How do I configure mount for my new hard drive?

Tags: mount

I have a new SSD and used Gparted to format it to the ext3 filesystem - that went smoothly but now I can't access it.

I right click on the drive icon in Nautilus under "Devices" and check the permissions - it says that the owner is root and I don't know how to change that.

Comment: What are you trying to change the permissions of? A file or folder on the partition?

Comment: the whole file I believe

Comment: What do you mean by "file"? Is it an actual file on the filesystem? Perhaps you can explain what your goal is and exactly what you have tried.

Comment: i click on the file pin on the side bar than click on the ssd under devices than right click on it and go to properties. I go to permissions to change the access so i can read and right but the owner is labeled as root

Comment: You don't "make a hard drive executable"

Comment: that does not work

Comment: Which file are you refering to? Is it in `/dev`?

Comment: the answer below left me with this ERROR:nautilus-properties-window.c:1836:schedule_owner_change_timeout: assertion failed: (NAUTILUS_IS_FILE (file))

Answer (score 1):

For doing it graphically, a simple way would be to use this in terminal:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

And then modify these to be <kbd>Read & Write</kbd>:
 [image: permissions]

Answer (score 1):

CLI solution:

```
sudo chown user:group mountpoint.
```

So, for example if your drive is mount to /media/foobar is my username is tux, and group is penguins.

```
sudo chown tux:penguins /media/foobar
```